# Casting from type object to a class

Tags: java, arrays, casting, arraylist

I'm currently trying to populate an array of of objects of the type `Stipulations` which is a class which is an

```
public abstract interface
```

My method of populating this array is as follows where `popStipAttr` is a simple switch statement.

```
    public static Stipulations[] popStipArr(ZASAllocation zasAlloc) 

    {
          //ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<Stipulations> stipAL  = new ArrayList<Stipulations>();

          for(int i = 0; i < NoStip; i++)
          {
          stipAL.add(popStipAttr(i,zasAlloc));
          }

          Stipulations[] StipArr =  (Stipulations[]) stipAL.toArray();
          return StipArr;
    }
```

However I get the error about casting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lc.Stipulations;
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here I created the arraylist of the same type, why would coverting it to an array of that type throw this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing in

```
Stipulations[] StipArr =  (Stipulations[]) stipAL.toArray();
```

is calling the method on the java.util.List class

```
Object[] toArray();
```

which is returning you an Object[] which cant be cast to your Stipulations[]
What you want to be calling is the method on java.util.List

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

which will return you the array with your type.
So try

```
Stipulations[] StipArr =  stipAL.toArray(new Stipulations[stipAL.size()]);
```

It is a strange syntax which tends to pollute the code and for this reason and a few others I always try to use Lists where possible and never convert to and from Arrays unless absolutely necessary like an external API not under my control requires it

Comment: Sorry a bit late with this, got distracted and the previous answer got in there never meant to duplicate the answer..

Comment: like the detail explanation.

And yup I'm using external jars

Answer (score 3):

[`ArrayList.toArray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) returns an `Object[]` (which, as stated in the message, can't be cast to `Stipulations[]`). [`ArrayList.toArray(T[] a)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) however, returns a `T[]`. Thus, change

```
Stipulations[] StipArr =  (Stipulations[]) stipAL.toArray();
```

to

```
Stipulations[] StipArr =  (Stipulations[]) stipAL.toArray(new Stipulations[0]);
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Oh, right. Just realized what may have caused the confusion. The leading `[` in `[Ljava.lang.Object;` indicates that it is an array. Same for `[Lc.Stipulations;`. Perhaps that's why you wrote *Casting from type object to a class* as title :-) Now you know anyway :-)

Comment: Nice one mate! Stack won't let me accept your answer for another 3mins